# Using both domain users and local users for Squid authentication?

Tags: authentication, squid

I'm working on a Squid proxy which needs to authenticate users against an Active Directory domain; this works fine, Samba was correctly set up and Squid authenticates users via `ntlm_auth`. Relevant lines in squid.conf:

```
auth_param ntlm program /usr/bin/ntlm_auth --helper-protocol=squid-2.5-ntlmssp
auth_param ntlm children 5
auth_param ntlm keep_alive on
acl Authenticated proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow Authenticated
http_access deny all
```

Now, I need a way to allow access to users which don't have a domain account. I know I could create an "internet user" account in the domain, but this would allow access, although limited, to domain resources (file shares, etc.); I need something that will allow only Internet access.

The ideal solution would be using a local account on the proxy server, either a Linux account or a Squid one; I know Squid supports this, but I'm unable to have it use ***both*** domain authentication and Squid/local authentication if domain auth is unsuccesful.

Can this be done? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, I need a way to allow access to users which don't have a domain account.  Can this be done?

Yes.

> How?

You can use an "external" ACL helper, which allows you to roll your own mechanism.  See the [Squid wiki "Multiple Source" entry](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Authenticate/MultipleSources) for more details.  This bit of pseudo-code lifted straight from there:

```
auth_param basic program /usr/local/bin/my-auth.pl
external_acl_type myAclType %SRC %LOGIN %{Proxy-Authorization} /usr/local/bin/my-acl.pl
acl MyAcl external myAclType
http_access allow MyAcl
```

... where my-auth.pl is a bit of perl script that performs the actual authentication, and returns `OK` or `ERR` as the result.

Comment: I had actually thouthg about this... but I'd like to know if there was some built-in way to do it.

Comment: There are several helper modules in `/usr/lib/squid` (or `/usr/lib64/squid` for 64-bit) that may be of interest to you.  Unfortunately, the one that looked to be most promising - `squid_unix_group` - requires that you not be using shadow passwords, which I'm assuming at this point you probably are (most installations do this out-of-the-box).  If you have an LDAP install separate from AD, `squid_ldap_auth` might be promising too.

Answer (score 1):

create a restricted domain user (isolated OU). from squid, create a squid ldap auth that will allow the user to use internet.